# Open image files based on header?

Tags: files, linux-mint, nemo

Very new Linux user here!

Okay, so in Windows, when I have a jpg file saved as x.png it doesn't matter much. I can open it and even the thumbnail works. Linux Mint (Nemo Explorer) doesn't show me the thumbnail and the image viewer always tells me that the header doesn't match the extension. Is there no way to just treat and open it as the file it is without manually renaming it? (For some reason pictures downloaded from various websites often just seem to have the wrong extension)

Comment: Also does a png-encoded file named .jpg have exif-tags?

Comment: FWIW, most shell-based image viewers (eg ImageMagick's `display`) should open such files without caring about the extension, or will allow you to specify the image format in the command line.